# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType of column score is not supported

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, k-means

I can't implement `kmeans` for the column `"score"` of my dataset loaded from `mongodb` with `spark`.

Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
 JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
  Dataset<Row> df = rdd.toDF();

  Dataset<Row> dataset = df.select("score");
   dataset.show();

  VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
            .setInputCols(new String[]{"score"})
            .setOutputCol("features");

        Dataset<Row> vectorized_df = assembler.transform(dataset);
       // vectorized_df.show();
        KMeans kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L);
        KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(dataset);

Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(dataset);
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception ?

Comment: Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(dataset);